# Refresh Excel with External Data from Orcale with password in Python

Tags: python, excel, passwords, win32com

I have an excel that updates data from an oracle server, normally I do it by hand, but I want to automate it with python, I know that it can be done with win32com, but it won't let me automate entering the password.
Thank you

```
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(<path_to_excel_workbook>)
wb.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
wb.Save()
xlapp.Quit()
```

but can I automate if the Oracle server have password?